# Not able to make a ajax request in django using postgresql

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, postgresql

So i've developed a django app,and i'm trying to POST something to Postgresql,i understand that CSRF token is necessary during an ajax request made to a view,which i have done,this is my csrf.js,which i've included in my header template

```
  // using jQuery
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue =   decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});
```

and this is my ajax request being made in a template

```
$.ajax({type: 'POST',
            url: '/sample/saveData/',                            // some data url
            data: {param: workHours.length, param1: $(getDayName[i]).text(),param2: bla,param3: bla1,param4: bla2}, 
                            // some params  
            success: function (response) {                  // callback
                if (response.result === 'OK') {
                    if (response.data && typeof(response.data) === 'object') {
                        // do something with the successful response.data
                        // e.g. response.data can be a JSON object
                    }
                } else {
                    window.alert(response.result);
                }
            }
           });
```

This is my view ,i hope this helps

```
def saveData(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
         # extract your params (also, remember to validate them)

        param = request.POST.get('param', None)
        param1 = request.POST.get('param1', None)
        param2 = request.POST.get('param2', None)
        param3 = request.POST.get('param3', None)
        param4 = request.POST.get('param4', None)
        stringData=datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')+" ("+param1+")"
        #another_param = request.POST.get('another param', None)
        #return HttpResponse(param, mimetype)
        p = Post(user="John",weekOfthemonth=param2 ,didAttend='Yes',date=stringData,numofHours=param,logIn=param3,logOut=param4)
    p.save()
    return HttpResponseBadRequest()
```

Comment: What's the problem? Show us your error message, or what goes wrong.

Comment: don't tell us your problem in the code. update your question please : )

Comment: @dirkgroten This is what i'm getting "Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
You are seeing this message because this site requires a CSRF cookie when submitting forms. This cookie is required for security reasons, to ensure that your browser is not being hijacked by third parties.
If you have configured your browser to disable cookies, please re-enable them, at least for this site, or for 'same-origin' requests."

Comment: @mohammedqudah i'm not sure what you are trying to ask ??

Comment: @sam i can solve this problem using *csrf_exempt* but this may not be secure?

Comment: no problem,could you tell me the solution @mohammedqudah

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use the csrf_exempt you dont have to use the jquery cookie function:
go to your `save_data` view and add this to it

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
@csrf_exempt
def save_data(request):
    [...] your code
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSRF token is present in django rendered templates.  Therefore, you just need to pass it in your jquery post.

I believe you can simplify most of your code and you wouldn't need the csrf.js either.  Change your data parameter of the $.ajax call to include the csrf token.

```
        data: {param: workHours.length, 
               param1: $(getDayName[i]).text(),
               param2: bla,
               param3: bla1,
               param4: bla2,
               csrfmiddlewaretoken: document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value},
```